# Why aerosol forms when you take a hot shower in a very cold day?

Tags: thermodynamics

When temperature is about $\pu{17 ^\circ C}$ and I open the hot shower in maximum temperature (for a common electric shower) the air gets almost immediately full of droplets and this lasts the entire bath.

I guess there is water vapor in the air and it gets cooled fast and condenses. If this is true, I don't get where the vapor comes from.

Comment: I guess you heard about mist? Or that water vaporises?

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, I did. As you can see in my question. I understand the vaporization of water, and its condensation. My questions is not about those generic phenomena but about the specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As air temperature increases(in the vicinity of the hot shower) air can hold more water molecules, or with more technical terms: the saturation water pressure increases with the temperature.
Near the water, the air temperature is high and since there's plenty of hot water that evaporates then the vapor pressure increases. Then because of convective motion, new cold air replaces the hot one and it becomes full of water vapor as well. The previously warm air is now far away from the hot water and it is starting to cool down. When its temperature decreases it can't hold so many water molecules and therefore you observe the small droplets of condensed water.

[image]

Ref. picture https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/phaseeqia/vapourpress.html

[image]